# SQL IN() not working properly

Tags: sql

Here is my query, but the result shown is wrong.

```
SELECT winner 
FROM nobel
WHERE
  subject = 'Economics' AND
  yr IN (
    SELECT min('yr')  
    FROM nobel
    WHERE subject = 'Economics'
  );
```

Comment: Show us **sample data**, show us what gets in fact selected, and explain *why* this is "wrong" .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is the quotes wrapping the `yr` inside the `MIN()` , which makes the optimizer address this as a string  which causes it to be evaluated as `MIN(constant_value)` which is always `constant_value` .

Try:

```
SELECT winner FROM nobel 
WHERE subject='Economics'
      AND yr IN (SELECT min(yr) FROM nobel WHERE subject='Economics');
```

Comment: yes,thanks a lot! I make a little mistake...thank you  for  your  answer!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the single quotes around `yr` as @sagi points out.  I just want to point out that a correlated clause is more typical for such a query along with `=`:

```
SELECT n.winner
FROM nobel n
WHERE n.subject = 'Economics' AND
      n.yr = (SELECT min(yr) FROM nobel n2 WHERE n2.subject = n.subject);
```

The use of `=` versus `in` here might seem like a minor point to you.  However, `=` says that at  most one row is being returned and `in` suggests that multiple rows could be returned.  This is an important difference for the SQL optimizer.

Comment: yes,thanks a lot! I make a little mistake...thank you  for  your  answer!And i try to use '=' instead of 'IN' and result is also correct,but it shows two rows because there are two winners .So maybe you said " = says that at most one row is being returned" hava something wrong or i misunderstand??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT winner 
FROM nobel
WHERE
  subject = 'Economics' AND
  yr IN (
        SELECT min(yr)  # ---> just remove quotes in your query, it will work  
        FROM nobel
        WHERE subject = 'Economics'
    );
```